# amazon ec2 instance stopped being accessible

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, freebsd

Up until this morning, I had a website running on ec2 (freeBSD, ami-8cce3fe5, running django/uwsgi/nginx), with an elastic ip of 50.19.97.56 . The site was being served, and I could ssh into the instance. Now the site is down and I can't even ssh into the instance.

As I hadn't made any changes while I was asleep, I thought maybe the instance had just crashed, so I restarted it, but to no avail:

when i try to ssh into it, the request just times out. pinging the ip also times out. pointing a browser to it's public dns (ec2-50-19-97-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com) also times out.

Although I haven't messed with security groups at all, these are the TCP ports for reference:

```
0 - 65535   sg-3ab01353 (default)
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
5080        0.0.0.0/0
```

Also, the system log that I can get from the amazon dashboard does not seem to contain any error messages. (the last entry is "Starting background file system checks in 60 seconds. Sat Jul  2 14:49:18 UTC 2011")

Answer (score 0):

If you have backups of everything, I would suggest relaunching the instance instead of simply restarting it. Also, have you contacted Amazon support? Give them the instance ID, and they might be able to resurrect it.